# Ios tableview how to find number of rows in a section?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a dynamic array. I need to display tableview as following scenario...
In the First cell i need to display 1 item.
In the second cell i need to display 2 items.
In the third cell i need to display 3 items.
In the forth cell i need to display 1 item.
In the fifth cell i need to display 2 items.
In the sixth cell i need to display 3 items.
and so on...
Could any one please suggest how to return no of rows in a section.

[image]

Comment: You can design three cells in table view storyboard. then by using identifier you can access any cell you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
int noOfRow = total/2 + ceil((total % 3)/3.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic for this is:

```
NoOfRows = TotalCount / 2
```

For e.g.:

```
If last value is 6 then, total no of rows are (6 / 2) = 3
If last value is 12 then, total no of rows are (12 / 2) = 6
```

You have to think logical that's it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank u for quick response. but if the last number is 4 then no of rows=(4/2)=2 as per your logic. where as 4 should be displayed in 3 rd cell as per my requirement and no of rows in this scenario should be 3.

Answer (score 1):

A faster method might be:

Notice in the divide by 2 method, most numbers work. The ones don't work are:
2, 4, 8, 10... basically, even numbers that aren't divisible by 6.

So we can come up with something like:

```
int count = array.count;
if (count % 2 == 0 && count % 6 != 0) {
    count + 2;
}
int rows = ceilf(count / 2);
```

Or we can write a for loop:

```
int counter = array.size;
int rows = 0;
int dec = 1;

while (counter > 0) {
    rows++;
    counter - dec;
    dec = dec % 3 + 1;
}
```

The for loop is of course, slower.

Comment: i think it should be while(counter>0)

Comment: I think the first method would be a lot faster! And yeah, wrote it and didn't check before submitting...